# A way to employ the same set of rules that are used by the compiler to match the method in GetMethod(..)

Tags: c#, .net, aop, roslyn

I am writing an AOP against an old legacy class that does not have the benefit of a built in IoC container. I am employing the power of dynamic types, using the `DynamicObject` derived class.  When I use the

`mi = obj.GetType().GetMethod(methNm, parmType);`

if the parameters types (represented by parmType, above) are not exactly the types that the method was declared with, then the above GetMthod(..) will not find the method.

My question to you is:
Do you know of a way, potentially using Roslyn's semantic model, to employ the same set of rules that are used by the compiler to match the method in GetMethod(..) to the "best choice" of a method?

Comment: If you're running against source (with csproj), you can easily use Roslyn.

Answer (score 0):

This logic is already implemented in Microsoft.CSharp.dll so invocations through the dynamic keyword can pick the right method too. If you can't just use that mechanism, you could look at the [runtime binder code](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/tree/master/src/Microsoft.CSharp/src/Microsoft/CSharp/RuntimeBinder) and figure out the appropriate way to incorporate it. You could call it directly (the entrypoints needed are public) without having to rebuild the code.

Comment: Jason, thank you.  Would you know of a an example I can follow?

Comment: I don't, unfortunately. ILSpy (or other disassembly tool) would let you know how the compiler generates calls that use this. You could also look at the compiler directly (it's open source) but that might be a bit too confusing.